# Trying to submit form action via ajax, getting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which is returning a undefined value for the `.prop('action')`

I am not quite sure why

Any thoughts?

```
$(function() {
            $('#generalContactForm').submit(function(event) {
                var formEl = this;
                var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]', formEl);
                var formData = {
                    'firstName'     : $('input[name=firstName]').val(),
                    'lastName'      : $('input[name=lastName]').val(),
                    'phoneNumber'   : $('input[name=phoneNumber]').val(),
                    'email'         : $('input[name=email]').val(),
                    'numberofGuests': $('input[name=numberofGuests]').val(),
                    'eventType': $('input[name=eventType]').val(),
                    'alcohol': $('input[name=alcohol]').val(),
                    'contactTime': $('input[name=contactTime]').val(),
                    'eventDate': $('input[name=eventDate]').val(),
                    'contactTextarea': $('input[name=contactTextarea]').val(),
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : formEl.prop('action'),
                    data : formData,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Comment: use formEl.attr('action') instead of prop.

Comment: Still getting same Error. See link http://g.recordit.co/Ss3x6mVTy3.gif

Comment: Why not use $(formEl).serialize()?

Comment: serialize does the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h4cvxypb/ seems working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function on a jquery object

```
$(formEl).prop('action')
```